# Dojo addOnLoad fires before widget loaded in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, tabcontainer

I am using both IE and Firefox for testing. The Dojo addOnLoad works for both browsers BUT for Firefox, it fires before my Dojo `TabContainer` is initialised. For IE, it is working fine. Is there any other Dojo / Javascript / jQuery method to circumvent this problem?

Script

```
<script>
dojo.addOnLoad( function(){
      alert("Tabcontainer loaded");

});
</script>
```

TabContainer

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="TabContainer">
```

Comment: you have tagged both `dojo` and `jquery` they might conflict ;)

Comment: I dont think so, I have implemented both in my web application :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it! This is done by including the first jsp page using the `<%@include>` This will definitely initialise the TabContainer so that future tabs can be added.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, but I haven't used Dojo in over a year, so I've forgotten it all.  Maybe try dojo.ready(), or you could try adding `djconfig="parseOnLoad:true"` to the `<script>` tag where you include the Dojo JS file.  I have no idea if either of these methods will work, but it can't hurt to try :)

Edit: maybe a call to dojo.parser.parse(); in your onload handler will do the trick? (in conjunction with parseOnLoad:false?)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. have tried both methods but it doesnt work